# Understanding Baby-Step Giant-Step Algorithm and discrete logarithm

Tags: discrete-logarithm, group-theory

Studying the Baby-Step/Giant-Step Algorithm, I have some questions:

1. In the algorithm, $p$ is the order of group, $x$ is solution. We rewrite $x = i * m + k $, but why do we make $m =\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor$, rather than something else like $\lfloor {p/2}\rfloor$?
2. (a) The time complexity is $O(\sqrt{p})$. If we make sufficient large $p$, then why is it difficult for compute the discrete logarithm computation in group $G$ of such order $p$?
   (b) It is said that the discrete logarithm computation is hard in group of prime order, particularly in subgroup (order $q$) of group of strong prime order (like order $p = 2*q + 1$, $q$ and $p$ is prime); why is that?

Comment: can you explain more detail about 2(b) ? I read the Polih-Hellman,  is it because subgroup of prime order q is hard to compute , thus it cannot apply the Chinese remainder theorem to recover the final solution x ?Is there no any efficient algorithm to solve DLP in group of prime order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. In the algorithm, $p$ is the order of group, $x$ is solution. We rewrite $x = i * m + k $, but why do we make $m =\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor$, rather than something else like $\lfloor {p/2}\rfloor$?

The time taken by Big Step-Little Step is $O( m + p/m )$ (the $O(m)$ term comes from the time taken iterating through the various $k$ values, the $O(p/m)$ term comes from the time taken iterating through the various $i$ values.

It should be easy to see that that time is minimized if $m \approx \sqrt{p}$

> 2. (a) The time complexity is $O(\sqrt{p})$. If we make sufficient large $p$, then why is it difficult for compute the discrete logarithm computation in group $G$ of such order $p$?

If $p$ is quite large, then $\sqrt{p}$ is also large (even if it isn't as large as $p$); for example, if we want $\sqrt{p} \ge 2^{128}$ so that the number of steps that Big Step-Little Step takes is infeasibly large, we just take $p \ge 2^{256}$.

Just one note: if we're working in the group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$, then there are other attacks against the Discrete Log problem other than the generic Big Step-Little Step (and Rho) algorithms; hence we generally need a much larger $p$

> 2. (b) It is said that the discrete logarithm computation is hard in group of prime order, particularly in subgroup (order $q$) of group of strong prime order (like order $p = 2*q + 1$, $q$ and $p$ is prime); why is that?

If we are working in the group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ (that is, the multiplicative group modulo $p$), well, that group has a size $p-1$; any prime subgroup will have a size $q$ which is a divisor of $p-1$.  One way (but not the only way) to make sure that there is a good $q$ is to make $p$ a "safe prime", that is, a prime such that $q = (p-1)/2$ is also prime.

On the other hand, that applies only to the group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$; if you go to (say) Elliptic Curve groups, there is no corresponding reason to prefer safe primes (either for the characteristic or the group size).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!But I still confuse that why discrete logarithm computation is hard in group of prime order ? is it because from which we cannot use efficient algorithm like Rho algorithms?

Comment: @Laura: why the dlog problem is hard for some groups?  Well, no one really knows that; all we know is that there are groups where the best known algorithm is infeasible.  Now, if we're working on a group with a composite order of known factorization, we can solve it by solving the dlog group in the various prime subgroups; hence it is considerably easier than a group of prime order of about the same size; hence we prefer groups of prime order.  BTW: the (Pollard) Rho algorithm is a generic one; it takes a constant factor more computation than Big Step/Little Step, but takes far less memory...